# How to do specific task depending on Yes/No confirmation panel in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a BaseAdapter which has a ListView and it has a lot of rows .
I have implemented the onItemClickListener's `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,long id)` .
I have a `AlertDialog` inside that `onItemClickListener` .
I want to delete the selected row of listView depending on the AlertDialog's Yes/No confirmation.
The problem is that , when I am inside the AlertDialog I can't achieve the index(`pos`) of the selected item of the listView and so cannot delete the row from the listView.

How can i get the selected item's index inside the AlertDialog ?
Is there any other alternative to using AlertDialog ?

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                long id) {

            Log.d("Test","The selected position is "+pos);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(parent.getContext());
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
        }

    });

DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which){
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            //Delete the selected row from list view and refresh            
            break;

        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
            //Nothing
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried setting pos to final?

Comment: That won't help, that is totally out of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a member variable (public or private) in the main activity. Once selected, update your variable and you'll be able to access that within your onClick. Something like:

Within the activity:

```
private int iClickedItem = 0;
```

Within the click:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
            long id) {

        Log.d("Test","The selected position is "+pos);

        iClickedItem = pos;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(parent.getContext());
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
    }

});
```

Within the Dialog:

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which){
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            //Delete the selected row from list view and refresh
            // should be able to access iClickedItem here
            break;

        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
            //Nothing
            // and here!
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Obviously, this hasn't been tested, I've just edited your code. In principle, it should be fine though :)

Comment: Thanks , it worked , Why this simple solution didn't reach my mind earlier :P

Comment: It's always the way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the last clicked item's position in an instance variable, so you can reach it anywhere in your class. You have to update this variable of course in your `onItemClick` method before you are launching the dialog.

Comment: Why did you downvote my answer? I told exactly the same as LokiSinclair.

Comment: Hi Thanks , I didn't downvote your answer , It's the solution actually :)